# "We only feel bad when our hands are numb." vs. "We only feel badly when our hands are numb."

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, complementation, linking-verbs

1. > We only feel bad when our hands are numb.
2. > We only feel badly when our hands are numb.

Which one is correct and why?

Comment: Please describe it with reasons so that I may catch it easily.

Comment: You can feel bad, as to be emotionally sad when your hands are numb --> "Oh no! My hands are numb! Whatever will I do!". Or you can feel things badly when your hands are numb --> "George, pass me the ketchup! My hands are numb and I can't feel anything! What does this feel like?"

Answer (score 1):

I feel happy/glad/angry/sad - Here the structure is to feel + adjective.
Not the way of feeling is angry, that does not make any sense. The underlying concept is: I feel that I am happy/glad/sad. Actually "to feel happy" is nothing but a variant for "to be happy".

There are groups of verbs which are connected with adjectives, and not adverbs.

Copula verbs:

1 to be

2 to become, to get, to turn, to grow

3 to remain, to stay, to keep

4 to seem, to appear

Some verbs of perception:

to look, to smell, to taste, to sound, to feel

In all these cases the adjective is a complement to the subject. These structures don't describe the manner how the verb action is performed.
There are a lot more verbs of the type vb + adj, but I don't want to write a grammar here. Actually these structures verb + adjective are variants of to be + adj.

http://www.usingenglish.com/glossary/copula-verb.html

Comment: Xpmai: respond to my second question.

Comment: I'm new user, sir. I can posts,  but I feel perplexity in tags searching

Comment: Can I say, I feel badly bad or I feel bad badly?

Comment: Hi teachers,  Help me please. Can I say that in my above sentence the word feel is action verb so we will take an adverb here . This is badly.  Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Some adverbs and adjectives have the same form but are used differently. It is the usage that will determine whether the word is an *adverb* or an *adjective*.

```
                   A                                   B
       He is **much** better today.        There is **much** work to do.
       I come here **daily**.             'The Pioneer' is a **daily** newspaper.
       Don't speak so **loud**.            He spoke in a **loud** voice.'
```

This is exactly what I found in 'A Comprehensive Grammar for Current English' *by Biswas and Myall*.

The first option is correct. "Bad" may look like an adjective but it is actually used as an adverb in the sentence. You do not need to change its form *(by adding "-ly")* to make it look like an adverb.

Like other adverbs, "bad" qualifies the verb "feel" in this particular context.

Note that the part of speech of a particular word is dependent upon its usage in the sentence.

Comment: Sir, I shared a few post. Please add your fruitful comments. Thanks

Comment: Hi! Where did you post your questions? I will be happy to help you.

Comment: Sir on this forum.

Comment: Yes, I found it out. I've posted my answer there. You can have a look at it.

Comment: Your grammar does not seem very reliable. You should check  what is said about copula/linking verbs.

Comment: Could you tell me what exactly seems unreliable?

Comment: Hi,  teachers,  Can you clarify the difference between them.  We use " to be honest" and " be careful" Why don't we use" be honest" and " be careful "

Comment: @AishwaryaAR, it seem unreliable to the average users here because of your incorrect grammar used although concepts and connotations are correct, look at my profile, downvotes for incorrect grammar mainly.

Comment: @XPMai: Could you please edit my post if you've found errors?

Comment: @XPMai  clear my concept.

Comment: @user124234, please [post it as a new question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) if you want to ask more questions about English _since there's a rule that disallow talking off-topic_. (also ensure that the question comply with the site's rules)